# Is basic HTTP auth in CouchDB safe enough for replication across EC2 regions?

Tags: security, http, authentication, couchdb, replication

I can appreciate that seeing "basic auth" and "safe enough" in the same sentence is a lot like reading "Is parachuting without a parachute still safe?", so I'll do my best to clarify what I am getting at.

From what I've seen online, people typically describe basic HTTP auth as being unsecured due to the credentials being passed in plain text from the client to the server; this leaves you open to having your credentials sniffed by a nefarious person or man-in-the-middle in a network configuration where your traffic may be passing through an untrusted point of access (e.g. an open AP at a coffee shop).

To keep the conversation between you and the server secure, the solution is to typically use an SSL-based connection, where your credentials might be sent in plain text, but the communication channel between you and the server is itself secured.

So, onto my question...

In the situation of replicating one CouchDB instance from an EC2 instance in one region (e.g. us-west) to another CouchDB instance in another region (e.g. singapore) the network traffic will be traveling across a path of what I would consider "trusted" backbone servers.

Given that (assuming I am not replicating highly sensitive data) would anyone/everyone consider basic HTTP auth for CouchDB replication sufficiently secure?

If not, please clarify what scenarios I am missing here that would make this setup unacceptable. I do understand for sensitive data this is not appropriate, I just want to better understand the ins and outs for non-sensitive data replicated over a relatively-trusted network.

Comment: Bruce Schneier makes an excellent point which people don't realize: authentication is more important than secrecy. Sure, it's nice if your bits fly down the wire encrypted. But it is far more important that you know, for sure, who is connecting (replicating). This is why nobody ever asks the question "should I run my couch in Admin Party?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bob is right, it is better to err on the side of caution, but I disagree. Bob could be right in this case (see details below), but the problem with his general approach is that it ignores the cost of paranoia. It leaves "peace dividend" money on the table. I prefer Bruce Schneier's assessment that it is a trade-off.

### Short answer

Start replicating now! Do not worry about HTTPS.

The *greatest* risk is not wire sniffing, but your own human error, followed by software bugs, which could destroy or corrupt your data. *Make a replica!*. If you will replicate regularly, plan to move to HTTPS or something equivalent (SSH tunnel, stunnel, VPN).

### Rationale

Is HTTPS is easy with CouchDB 1.1? It is as easy as HTTPS can possibly be, or in other words, no, it is not easy.

You have to make an SSL key pair, purchase a certificate or run your own certificate authority—you're not foolish enough to self-sign, of course! The user's hashed password is plainly visible from your remote couch! To protect against cracking, will you implement bi-directional SSL authentication? Does CouchDB support that? Maybe you need a VPN instead? What about the security of your key files? Don't check them into Subversion! And don't bundle them into your EC2 AMI! That defeats the purpose. You have to keep them separate and safe. When you deploy or restore from backup, copy them manually. Also, password-protect them so if somebody gets the files, they can't steal (or worse, modify!) your data. When you start CouchDB or replicate, you must manually input the password before replication will work.

In a nutshell, every security decision has a cost.

**A similar question is, "should I lock my house at night?** It depends. Your profile says you are in Tuscon, so you know that some neighborhoods are safe, while others are not. Yes, it is always safer to always lock all of your doors all of the time. But what is the cost to your time and mental health? The analogy breaks down a bit because time invested in worst-case security preparedness is much greater than twisting a bolt lock.

**Amazon EC2 is a moderately safe neighborhood.** The major risks are opportunistic, broad-spectrum scans for common errors. Basically, organized crime is scanning for common SSH accounts and web apps like Wordpress, so they can a credit card or other database.

**You are a small fish in a gigantic ocean. Nobody cares about you specifically.** Unless you are specifically targeted by a government or organized crime, or somebody with resources and motivation (hey, it's CouchDB—that happens!), then it's inefficient to worry about the boogeyman. Your adversaries are casting broad nets to get the biggest catch. Nobody is trying to spear-fish you.

I look at it like high-school integral calculus: measuring the area under the curve. Time goes to the right (x-axis). Risky behavior goes up (y-axis). When you do something risky you saved time and effort, but the the graph spikes upward. When you do something the safe way, it costs time and effort, but the graph moves down. Your goal is to minimize the long-term area under the curve, but each decision is case-by-case. Every day, most Americans ride in automobiles: the single most risky behavior in American life. We intuitively understand the risk-benefit trade-off. Activity on the Internet is the same.

Comment: Great reply Jason, thank you for all the detail. Shines a lot more light no the cost of security here as far as a barrier to launching/moving forward goes. It is good to at least be aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

As you imply, basic authentication without transport layer security is 100% insecure. Anyone on EC2 that can sniff your packets can see your password. Assuming that no one can is a mistake.

In CouchDB 1.1, you can enable native SSL. In earlier version, use stunnel. Adding SSL/TLS protection is so simple that there's really no excuse not to.

Comment: Robert, thank you for the reply. The part I'm specifically curious about is "anyone on ECS that CAN sniff your packets..." -- how would some unknown EC2 customer sniff my traffic? All the traffic is switched and except for the known ELB misdirection of 3rd party traffic during scale events, I'm not clear how someone else in EC2 would watch my traffic to/from end points they have no control over.

Comment: I'm not a network expert so I can't enumerate the ways to subvert security in a switched environment, but the assertion that it's safe to trust in just that seems very strong and needs justification. Also many people working within the EC2 service can sniff. End-to-end protection is easily achieved but if your data is truly not private, there's no need to protect it in transit.

Comment: Robert, agreed that there is no reason not to use an SSL transport given it is right there in CouchDB already, was just curious about vectors I may not have been aware of within EC2. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Good answer, Bob, but I disagree in this specific instance. I added my opinion as a separate answer.

Comment: I respect that argument but do not agree with it. Packet sniffing in a switched network is feasible, just not trivial. If your argument amounts to 'don't worry, it probably won't happen' then it's a fine argument as far as it goes. See http://serverfault.com/questions/52301/is-packet-sniffing-for-passwords-on-a-fully-switched-network-really-a-concern for more.

Comment: Yes, our answers seem superficially at odds; however, we are in fact (IMO) taking different positions on the risk/benefit spectrum. One quibble, however: if plaintext auth is "100%" insecure, then how insecure is Admin Party? 1,000%? 200%? Or is it also 100% insecure? But if it is also 100% insecure, that means there's no difference between Admin Party and plaintext auth which seems incorrect. My point is, there is always a spectrum of risk-benefit.

Comment: by 100% insecure I mean you are putting your entire cleartext password on the wire on every request. It's not possible to reveal it more often than that. We're both right, we were just talking about different scopes. My take on the primary question is that you should secure passwords in flight wherever possible (and I accept that setting HTTPS can be non-trivial, but between private nodes, I don't think so). I accept it's not personal if I get struck by lightning, it's just bad luck, but I'm still just as fried.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this statement from Amazon which may help anyone trying to understand the risk of packet sniffing on EC2.

> **Packet sniffing by other tenants**: It is not possible for a virtual instance running in promiscuous mode to receive or "sniff" traffic that is intended for a different virtual instance. While customers can place their interfaces into promiscuous mode, the hypervisor will not deliver any traffic to them that is not addressed to them. This includes two virtual instances that are owned by the same customer, even if they are located on the same physical host. Attacks such as ARP cache poisoning do not work within EC2. While Amazon EC2 does provide ample protection against one customer inadvertently or maliciously attempting to view another's data, as a standard practice customers should encrypt sensitive traffic.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1697

Comment: Very helpful and exactly what I was looking for (an official stance on the subject). Thank you.